# Parse an XML document using LINQ into sub XML documents

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I know that this must be asked and answers somewhere but I can't find it so I will ask it again.  I have the following vb.net code to pull an XML document.

```
    Dim getXML = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=xml&id=30076185,29253513"

    Dim doc As XDocument
    doc = XDocument.Load(getXML)
    Dim xmlDocs = doc.Root.Elements("PubmedArticle")
```

And it splits the PubmedArticleSet element into 2 PubmedArticle's
what I need to do is the save each of the xml documents into a MS SQL database as xml not as a stripped out string of just text.

My SQL code is

```
        sql.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@XMLData", SqlDbType.Xml)).Value = xmlDocs(i).Document.Root
```

I get an error of

```
     {"Failed to convert parameter value from a XElement to a String."} System.Exception {System.InvalidCastException}
```

I've tried to

```
     CSTR(xmlDocs(i).Document.Root)
```

but that gives a different error

```
      Message = "XML parsing: line 1, character 9668, illegal name character"
```

If I use the same code but cut and paste the xml into a TextBox it works fine so I must assume it has to do with my lack of understanding of the LINQ XML Document.

All suggestions are appreciated to help be save each Publication Document Element

Update:  I can do it fine using a XMLDocument with the following code.

```
        Dim docXML As New XmlDocument

        docXML.Load(getXML)

        For Each node As XmlNode In docXML.SelectNodes("/PubmedArticleSet/PubmedArticle")
            Dim pubmed As String = ""
            Dim xmlData As String = "<PubmedArticleSet><PubmedArticle>" + node.InnerXml + "</PubmedArticle></PubmedArticleSet>"
            'Data capture for Pubmed and pmc
            Dim node1a As XmlNodeList = node.SelectNodes("PubmedData/ArticleIdList")
            For Each node1a1 As XmlNode In node1a
                pubmed = node1a1.SelectSingleNode("ArticleId[@IdType='pubmed']").InnerText

            Next

            UpdateDatabaseXML(xmlData, pubmed, 1835)

        Next
```

Will LINQ do the same thing or should I stay with an XMLDocument?

Comment: Change From : xmlDocs(i).Document.Root To : xmlDocs(i)

Comment: That then strips out all of the XML formatting <>

Comment: Just the opposite.  XmlDocs is a XElement not an XDocument.  There is no Document in an XElement.